# CMAKE install command post process the file

Tags: linux, cmake

I am installing static file using CMake's `INSTALL` command. 
I want to post process the output file using CMake.

For example, static files have a string like

```
v={{VERSION}}
```

I want to replace `{{VERSION}}` in the output files.

Is this possible with CMake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but preprocessing is usually done at `cmake` invocation step, not during install. This is done using [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) command.

Note that `configure_file()` supports substituting values only in `${}` or `@@`, so if you really need to configure a file with `{{}}`, you might end up writing your own function using the CMake command [`file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html).

Finally, you need to install your configured file. Be sure to

```
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/your.file)
```

and not just

```
install(FILES your.file)
```

since the latter command would install your source file.

Comment: Is there any way to use configure_file on multiple files or based on regular expression . 
I want to update all *.txt files found in a directory

Comment: Yes, it is. You will need to use `file(GLOB MY_FILES "*.txt")` to create a list of your files and `foreach(FILE ${MY_FILES})` to call `configure_file()` for each of your files.